# Unable to set custom clientInfo in Oracle

Tags: java, connection, oracle12c

I am using oracle 12 c and want to add custom client info to the connection object. Here is the code in Java 8.

```
connection.setClientInfo("USER.USERID",user);
```

But it get error

```
ORA-28267: Invalid Namspace Value.
```

I am not sure what namespaces are available to use? Can't find any documentations.

I found [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-standards-support.html#GUID-74632540-DE51-49F2-8DB8-D00E1A1EC299) that says one can set any namespace.key, but its not accepting any key value pair.

any help would be appreciated!